# Android Studio | Kotlin Bluetooth | Manage current connection

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, arduino, bluetooth

I want to make an android app, where I can send data (a string or 3 8bit ints) via bluetooth.

The result should be an app that can send data via bluetooth to an arduino uno (HC-05). This arduino should then use those values to change the color of a neopixel rgb strip.

My app already has 3 seekbars (r, g, b) that have values from 0 to 255. I also have an image to represent if bluetooth is offline or online (id in code: "@+id/bluetoothImg"), some text and another button that I need help with.

The first button can turn on bluetooth. It works all fine. The second button should transfer the values from those 3 seekbars to the arduino.

I want to do it like that:

The user should connect him with the Bluetooth named "LED Strip" with his normal settings.

Then the app should check if the connected device has the name "LED Strip" and if yes, then send those 3 values via bluetooth. But the problem I have is I dont know how to check the connected (And not all paired!!) device for its name or how to manage an existing bluetooth connection. Here my code that I have till now. I also made a comment in my Kotlin code what I want to do.

The look of the app: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlH4s.jpg

If some of you need more information, please comment or contact me. Thank you.

activity_xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/colin_s_led_strip"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bluetoothImg"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_bluetooth_off"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bluetoothStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/bluetooth_is_unavailable"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/turnOnBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:text="@string/turn_on_bluetooth"
        android:minWidth="200dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/connectToDevice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:text="@string/connect_to_strip"
        android:minWidth="200dp" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/red"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="30dp" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/green"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/blue"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/colorToShow"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/white"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt:

```
package de.virtualivin.ledforcar

import android.app.Activity
import android.bluetooth.*
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.SeekBar
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val REQUEST_CODE_ENABLE_BT:Int = 1
    private val REQUEST_CODE_DISCOVERABLE_BT:Int = 2

    //Bluetooth Adapter
    lateinit var bAdapter: BluetoothAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        bAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()

        //Check if Adapter is available
        if (bAdapter == null) {
            bluetoothStatus.text = "Bluetooth is unavailable"
        } else {
            bluetoothStatus.text = "Bluetooth is available"
        }

        //Check if Bluetooth is enabled
        if (bAdapter.isEnabled) {
            bluetoothImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bluetooth_on)
            turnOnBtn.text = "Bluetooth is online"
        } else {
            bluetoothImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bluetooth_off)
            turnOnBtn.text = "Turn on Bluetooth"
        }

        turnOnBtn.setOnClickListener {
            if (bAdapter.isEnabled) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth already on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {
                val intent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_ENABLE_BT)
            }
        }

        connectToDevice.setOnClickListener {
            if (bAdapter.isEnabled) {
                //Check if bAdapter is already connected to a device
                    //Check if bAdapter is connected to device named LED Strip
                        //Send data to Arduino Uno
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth must be on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

        red.max = 255;
        red.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
            override fun onProgressChanged(p0: SeekBar?, p1: Int, p2: Boolean) {
                colorToShow.setColorFilter(Color.rgb(red.progress, green.progress, blue.progress))
            }

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {
                //Nothing
            }

            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {
                //Nothing
            }

        })

        green.max = 255;
        green.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
            override fun onProgressChanged(p0: SeekBar?, p1: Int, p2: Boolean) {
                colorToShow.setColorFilter(Color.rgb(red.progress, green.progress, blue.progress))
            }

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {
                //Nothing
            }

            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {
                //Nothing
            }

        })

        blue.max = 255;
        blue.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
            override fun onProgressChanged(p0: SeekBar?, p1: Int, p2: Boolean) {
                colorToShow.setColorFilter(Color.rgb(red.progress, green.progress, blue.progress))
            }

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {
                //Nothing
            }

            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {
                //Nothing
            }

        })
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        when(requestCode) {
            REQUEST_CODE_ENABLE_BT ->
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    bluetoothImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bluetooth_on)
                    turnOnBtn.text = "Bluetooth is online"
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is now on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } else {
                    bluetoothImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bluetooth_off)
                    turnOnBtn.text = "Turn on Bluetooth"
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Could not turn on bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
}
```